# AngularJS promise return value from inside a service seems to change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a service to make a series of API-Calls whenever I poll new data:

```
angular.module('dashboardApp')
.service('data', function($http, $q) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.server = function() {
      /*get server address*/
    };
    _this.polling = function() {
      _this.myData = {};
      console.log('_this.myData emptied');
    }
    _this.getData = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      _this.server().then(function(serverconf) {
         /*...*/
         deferred.resolve();
      };
      var getDataA = function(){
           /*---*/
           _this.myData = {a : 'a'};
      };
      var getDataB = function(){/*...*/};
      var getDataC = function(){/*...*/};
      var promiseA = deferred.promise.then(getDataA);
      var promiseB = deferred.promise.then(getDataB);
      var promise = $q.all([pomiseA,pomiseB]).then(function(resp){
          /* do something here */
      }).then(getDataC).then(function(resp2){
         /*...*/
         _this.myData = {c : 'c'};
         return _this.myData;
    });
    return promise;
   };
   return {
      getData = _this.getData,
      polling = _this.polling,
   };
};
```

I am changing my data throughout my API-calls in the service. And I can see that the data changes inside the controller making the call everytime an API-Call was successfull.

```
var polling = function() {
  data.getData().then(function(myData) {
    $scope.myDataset = myData;
    setTimeout(function() {
      data.polling();
      polling();
    }, 3000);
  });
};
$scope.$watch('myDataSet', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.debug(newVal);
}, true);
//output:
//{}
//{a:'a'}
//{b:'b'}
```

I deactivated everything else, so I am pretty sure the new data is coming from the service itself.

Edit: Forgot some important stuff when I simplified the code.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are seeing vs. what you are supposed to see. What is `data.mscons`? Also, why is there a `deferred` which is never resolved/rejected? You should also use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` to trigger a digest cycle automatically, otherwise your `$watch` would trigger only on the next iteration... *Also*, `.service` returns a constructor function, whereas you ought to use `.factory`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change `data.mscons` (how it is called in my program) to `data.getData()`. Also I forgot to include the call of `resolve` in this example. I originally used `$timeout`, but then I read something about [memory leaks](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1522) and changed it to `setTimeout`. I am looking into the use of `.factory` right now...

Comment: Ok.. but what is the expected result/output?

Comment: In my controller I set `$scope.myDataset` to the return value of `getData` which I expect to be `{c,'c'}` as this is the last return value of the promise-chain.

Comment: So, your question is about why you are seeing intermittent results? You are $watching *and* changing the object being watched with almost every `.then` in your service

Comment: Yes, that is my problem! I don't understand, why the output changes eventhough the promise hasn't been resolved completely. I tried to wrap my head around the concept of promises and services, but I seem to have missed something...

Comment: well... actually, it shouldn't happen in your example, since you are assigning the whole object... it would have happened if you were changing the property of the same object, the `$watch` would fire regardless of your promise: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kbQwsI9pFjs2tKhRLtpt?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of NewDev, I think the problem is that I return a `$http`-promise in each of my promises.

But since I had not enough time to dig deeper, I worked out a quick work-around which fixed my problem:

```
var polling = function() {
  data.getData().then(function(myData) {
    $scope.returned = true;
    $scope.myDataSet = myData;
    setTimeout(function() {
      data.polling();
      polling();
    }, 3000);
 });
};
$scope.$watch('myDataSet', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   if($scope.returned === true){
      $scope.myDataSet = newVal;
      $scope.returned = false;
   }else{
      $scope.myDataSet = oldVal;
   }
}, true);
```

This way I am monitoring if the new data was returned after all promises have been resolved and control the update this way.